# Folders on a URL

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am trying to check for a folders on a URL path like "xxx.xxx.com/MyFiles/Folder1". I would like to check if Folder 1 exists.

```
If yes then
  'do something
else
  create a folder
  ' do the same thing as above
end if
```

Is it possible to do it using vb.net as the program is a standalone app which resides on a PC and transfers files to the URL. I am using webclient to do the upload which works fine if there is a folder already. The problem lies when the folder does not exist.

Any help appreciated
Thanks

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for: [VB.NET - Check if URL is a directory or file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15858953/vb-net-check-if-url-is-a-directory-or-file)

Comment: I can check if it is a folder or not, but if it is not how do I create one?

Comment: You Can use Directory.CreateDirectory(path), can't you?

Comment: Good answer, I was just about to do it, will report back ASAP. Thanks Aldipa

Comment: why do you not use ftp uploading. you can create directory in the user folders, but you will have to make sure the application pool user has rights to create the directory.

Comment: It thows up NotSupportedException. I thought createdirectory only works on networked paths not urls.

Comment: ftp is blocked by firewall / proxy so it is not an option :-(

Comment: Not sure, never did before, but it seems like you've got the same problem asked here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7424274/avoiding-notsupportedexception-using-createdirectory-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used a webservice on the server. The webservice checks whether the folder exists or not. If it does not it creates one, figured out it was much easier done this way and also secure.

Answer (score 0):

this is only possible when the webserver give you the permission. It means every Webserver has a .htaccess file if there is no permission for this you can not check if the folder or file is exist.

Comment: I have used the code above to check whether it is a file or not so I believe I have the right permissions. Also I CAN upload a file if the folder exists.